# Let $G=\langle x, y\mid x^2, y^2\rangle$. Understanding proof $\exists H\unlhd G$ s.t. $[G:H]=2$.

Tags: group-theory, proof-explanation, cyclic-groups, normal-subgroups

I met some problem during googling.

The problem and its solution are next.

and I'm wondering about ***2nd YELLOW BOX***

$$
$$

[image]

$$
$$
**Why does $G$ have a unique element of order $2$ in case of $H=G$ ?**

$$
$$

> ***The next is "my opinion" for 2nd YELLOW BOX...***
>
> If $H=G=H \cup Hx$ , then $Hx=H$

> So, $x=h^k$ for some $k \in Z-\{0\} $.
>
> By hypothesis for $|x|=2$ , I get $|h^k|=2$.
>
> Therefore $G=\{1, h, h^2, \cdots , h^k , ... , h^{2k-1}   \}$, and $G$ has an unique element $h^k$ of order $2$.

Is my opinion RIGHT?

I thought and thought AND THOUGHT **so many time** for digesting YELLOW BOX.. :-(

By any chance... Is it trivial thing?

OR Do you have any good idea for understanding YELLOW BOX?

Could you give me some advice, please?

Thanks for reading my question.

Comment: The first yellow box is just the definition of $H=\langle h\rangle$.

Comment: Oops.. I'm just wondering 2nd YELLOW BOX.. Sorry,, why I made two boxes...sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a quick answer to this: If $H = G$, then since $H$ is cyclic (it is generated by the element $h = xy$), $G$ must also be cyclic. Since it is cyclic, it is in particular abelian. Thus $x, y$ commute.

So we have two possibilities.

1. $x \neq y$
2. $x = y$

You should be able to show that the first case is impossible since $G$ is cyclic. This leaves the second case, but this shows that there is only one element of order 2.

**Edit** This is not correct, as was pointed out in the comments. A better proof is that if $G$ is cyclic (by hypothesis, since $G = H$), then $G \cong \mathbb{Z}$ or $G \cong \mathbb{Z}/n$ for some $n$. In the first case, it has no elements of order 2, which obviously is not the case. In the second case, if $n$ is odd then there are also no elements of order 2. If $n$ is even, then you can check (try this with $\mathbb{Z}/6, \mathbb{Z}/8$ and a few others if you prefer) that there must be a unique element of order two, namely $[n/2]$. Since by assumption $x \neq y$, here is your contradiction.

Comment: Yeah, fair enough. I (admittedly) didn't read the whole question, but just the highlighted bit. Ooops!

Comment: Thanks for your answering. Could you read my opinion [the gray box]? Is that right thing? If I write right, then in case H=G.. the order of G must be finite, isn't it? Thank you.

Comment: and I focused on 'Hx=H". Thanks.

Comment: Yes, what you have written in the grey box is correct. Essentially, it is the same sort of argument that I have written in my edit.

Comment: Aha, in the now I understand certainly what you said. THANKS

Answer (score 5):

You said that $Hx\subset H$, but remember cosets are disjoint or equal! So $Hx=H$. Then, remembering $H=\langle h\rangle$ where $h=xy$, and assuming $Hx=H$,

- $y\in H$ as $h^{-1}x\in Hx=H$ but $h^{-1}x=y^{-1}$.
- $x\in H$ as $1x\in Hx=H$ but $1x=x$.

Hence, $G=\langle x, y\rangle\leq H$, so $G=H$ as required.

As $H$ is cyclic, this means that $G$ is cyclic. Now, cyclic groups of order $n$ contain unique subgroups of every order dividing $n$$^{\dagger}$, from which the "unique element of order $2$" follows. Alternatively, note that the number $n$ has at most one integer that is one half of it...

---

$^{\dagger}$ See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/410464/10513) math.SE answer for a proof of this fact.

Comment: And I edited Hx=H, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for answering. BUT I'd like to know what make you said 'the order of G is n(i.e. finite)' actually I wonder 2nd YELLOW BOX... Can 'my opinion(the gray box)' explain the finite order of G?

Comment: @user I only assumed that $G$ had order $n$ when I had proven that it was cyclic. As $\mathbb{Z}$ contains no elements of order 2, $G$ must be finite cyclic.

Comment: Aha thank you very much. Have a nice day.