# How many elements $a$ with $o(a)\mid 5$ in $\mathbb{Z}/360\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I am trying to understand why there are exactly $5$ elements of order dividing $5$ in $\mathbb{Z}/360\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange! What are the possible values $o(a)$? Do you know an element whose order divides 5? What could be the order of the other four elements?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $\mathbb{Z}/360\mathbb{Z}$ is a cyclic group. So there is exactly one subgroup of order $5.$ So...?

$\bf{EDIT:}$ This [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/410389/subgroups-of-a-cyclic-group-and-their-order) (kindly provided by *Bill Dubuque*) says that, if $G$ is a cyclic group of order $n$ and if $d$ is +ve integer dividing $n$, then there is a unique subgroup of $G$ order $d.$ Applying this result in this particular case $(n = 360, d=5),$ we get that $\mathbb{Z}/360\mathbb{Z}$ has a unique subgroup $H$ of order $5.$ Surely for any $a \in H, o(a)|5$ (why?). Now if there is an element of order $5$ in $G$ which is not in $H$ then that element will generate a subgroup of order $5$ which is different from $H.$ But his can't happen because the above mentioned result says that $H$ is unique.

Comment: See e.g. [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/410389/242) for proofs of said theorem.

Comment: i am still lost, why does this help me?

Comment: @IdoBen-Shaul: see the Edit. let me know if you have any doubt.