# Regarding the unique subfields of a cyclotomic field extension

Tags: galois-theory, cyclotomic-fields

What are the unique subfields $L$ of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{13})$ such that $[L:\mathbb{Q}]=2, 3, 4$, and $6$? I get that the Euler's totient function of $13$ is $12$ and that must have some relation, as its factors are listed above. Let's take the first case, $[L:\mathbb{Q}]=2$ and I'll show you why I'm confused.

I would assume for $[L:\mathbb{Q}]=2$ we have $\mathbb{Q}$-basis $\{e,\sigma\}$ where $\sigma: \zeta^x\mapsto\zeta^{x+6}$, because this cycles round our $\zeta^1$ to $\zeta^{12}$ in $2$ steps, however, why can we just miss out $\zeta^{13}=1$? Surely when it cycles from, say, $\zeta^6$ it goes $\zeta^6\mapsto \zeta^{12}\mapsto \zeta^{18}=\zeta^5\mapsto \zeta^{11}$ etc and we generate the whole group? Then $[L:\mathbb{Q}]\neq2$?

Sorry I'm not phrasing myself very well, but I honestly don't know how to. Thanks to all in advance!

Comment: Then what is the mapping I should be looking for?

Comment: Our basis for Q(ζ13)/Q is {ζ^1,ζ^2,ζ^3,ζ^4,ζ^5,ζ^6,ζ^7,ζ^8,ζ^9,ζ^10,ζ^11,ζ^12}, so how can there be a mapping that takes an element to itself after 2 iterations? Or am I wrong in thinking that is what [L:Q]=2 means?

Comment: In @DietrichBurde's notation, if $u \in U(p)$, (i.e., $u$ a non-zero element of $\mathbb F_{p}$) then every $\sigma\in {\rm Gal}(\mathbb Q(\zeta_p)/\mathbb Q  )$ is of the form $\sigma_u( \zeta^k) = \zeta^{ku}$, for all $k$. OK? And you forgot  $\zeta^0=1$ in your list above

Comment: the autormorphisms of $\mathbb{Q}(e^{2i \pi / 13}) / \mathbb{Q}$ are $\sigma(e^{2i \pi / 13}) = e^{2i k \pi / 13}$ for some integer $k$ such that $gcd(k,13)  = 1$. so the Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}(e^{2i \pi / 13}) / \mathbb{Q}$ is $((\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}_{13})^*,\times)$ which is $\simeq C_{12}$ the cyclic group with $12$ elements. let $g$ being a generator of the Galois group, the subgroups are the ones generated by $g^2$, $g^3$ and $g^6$,

Comment: hence by the[fundamental theorem of Galois theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_Galois_theory), the subfields are the ones fixed by those subgroups : $\mathbb{Q}(e^{12 i \pi / 13}), \mathbb{Q}(e^{ 6i \pi / 13})$ and $ \mathbb{Q}(e^{4 i \pi / 13})$ . is all this correct ?

Comment: @user1952009 - what about $g^4$? and your last comment is incorrect...  e.g., if $u\in \mathbb F_{13}^*$, then $\zeta^{4u} =\zeta^4$ implies $u=1$..

Comment: @peterag from my understanding I'm not missing 1 from that basis, as the standard basis is {1,ζ^1,ζ^2,ζ^3,ζ^4,ζ^5,ζ^6,ζ^7,ζ^8,ζ^9,ζ^10,ζ^11} which as ζ^12 can be written as -(1+ζ^1+ζ^2+ζ^3+ζ^4+ζ^5+ζ^6+ζ^7+ζ^8+ζ^9+ζ^10+ζ^11), gives us an equivalent basis of {ζ^1,ζ^2,ζ^3,ζ^4,ζ^5,ζ^6,ζ^7,ζ^8,ζ^9,ζ^10,ζ^11,ζ^12}, correct?

Comment: Ooops you're  right. shame.... Sorry!

Comment: @peterag : yes I forgot $g^4$ of course, but what I meant is not that the subfields are fixed pointwise but are fixed as a whole, i.e. $\sigma(x) \in K$ for every $x \in K$. so if an automorphism $\sigma$ of $\mathbb{Q}(e^{2i \pi/13})$ send for some $d | 12$ :  $K = \mathbb{Q}(e^{2i d\pi/13})$ to itself then $\sigma(e^{2i \pi/13}) = e^{n 2 (12/d) i \pi/13}$ for some $n, gcd(n,13) = 1$

Comment: @user1952009 The fields you listed are all the same field -  $\mathbb Q(\zeta_{13)}$ - by  your comment preceding the one that contains your list.  For instance, $(\zeta^6)^{-2} =\zeta$.

Comment: Okay, now I understand how the Galois groups are generated, but I'm still uncertain of what the unique subfields are, like what combination of ζ do we have in our subfield corresponding to the galois group {e, g^4, g^8}?

Comment: The Galois correspondence $H\mapsto\mathbb Q (\zeta)^H$ gives you the lattice of subfields. To see this explicitly, for $H$ a multiplicative subgroup of $\mathbb F^*$, play with the sum $$\sum_{u\in H} \zeta^u$$ (and their Galois conjugates) . Try $H= \mathbb (F_p^*)^2$, the squares, and  $H= \{\pm 1\}$. For the former, one gets a quadratic extension of $\mathbb Q$ - and this is related to quadratic reciprocity... For the latter case, the fixed field is the  maximal (totally) real subfield, and is $\mathbb Q(\cos 2\pi/13)$. You might have an easier time first playing with $p =5$ and $p=7$.

Comment: BTW the word Gaussian period shows up in this context - but it's not a bad idea to play at least a bit with the sums first before looking it up... You'll get your own way of understanding them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subfields of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$ for $p$ prime correspond to the subgroups of its Galois group $U(p)\cong C_{p-1}$. For $p=13$ we have to find the subgroups of the cyclic group $C_{12}$. We know that for each divisor $d\mid 12$ there exists exactly one subgroup of order $d$, because $C_{12}$ is cyclic - see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/410389/subgroups-of-a-cyclic-group-and-their-order).