# Let $G=\langle a\rangle$ be a cyclic group of order $n$. Show that, for every divisor $d$ of $n$, there exists a subgroup of $G$ whose order is $d$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

Let $G=\langle a\rangle$ be a cyclic group of order $n$. Show that, for every divisor $d$ of $n$, there exists a subgroup of $G$ whose order is $d$.

This time I have no approach. I haven't found any relation between the divisors of $n$ and the order of the subgroups of $G$. How would approach this?

Comment: It may not help you to think this way but there is a clear-cut way to deal with cyclic groups. A cyclic group is one which has a surjection from the additive group $\mathbb{Z}\to G$. In this case the kernel would be $n\mathbb{Z}$. Now the subgroups of $G$ and the subgroups containing $n\mathbb{Z}$ are in bijection. Now this should be obvious.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/410389/subgroups-of-a-cyclic-group-and-their-order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you realize $G$ as the set $\{0,1,\ldots, n-1\}$ with addition modulo $n=de$, then $\{0,e,2e,\ldots, (d-1)e\}$ is a subgroup of order $d$.

Comment: I like your idea. Would it be enough if I prove that this subgroup is a subgroup of G?

Comment: Isn't it obvious? $ke + le = (k+l)e$.

Comment: for the inverse can we say $ke+x=de$, so $x=e(d-k)$ where $k<d$?

Comment: Yes, the inverse of $ke$ is $(d-k)e$.

Comment: why? can you elaborate on that?, it's a little bit hard for me to see

Comment: Because $ke + (d-k)e = de = n$ which is zero modulo $n$. The point is that both the group operation as well as inversion are the same as i $G$ (that's part of the definition of a subgroup).

Comment: Oh didn't realize that you changed your answer XD

Answer (score 0):

‎
‎$ d‎ ‎\vert n ‎‎‎‎‎‎ ‎\Rightarrow ‎‎‎‎\exists k‎ ‎\in ‎‎\mathbb{N} ‎‎\qquad‎ st  ‎‎\qquad‎ n=kd ‎‎$‎‎‎‎

‎$ 1=‎ ‎‎a^n=a^kd=(a^k)^{d} ‎\Rightarrow ‎o(<a^k>)=d ‎‎$‎‎‎

then ‎$<a^k> \leq G ‎$ ‎and ‎‎$‎\vert ‎<a^k‎> \vert = d ‎$‎‎

Answer (score 0):

For any divisor d of n,we shall get an integer k such that dk=n. Now consider the element $a^k$ and show that the subgroup generated by it is the required one.