# All Subgroups of $Z_{200}$

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

### Cyclic Group $Z_{n}$

How do I find all the Subgroups of **$Z_{200}$** under additive modulo 200? *And how many subgroups are there?* I know the definition of subgroups but to find all the subgroups of such a large set is a bit difficult for me. Is there a smart way to find it?

> The answer to this question is 12 and I not sure if this is correct.

Comment: Denote $[m]$ the equivalence class of $m$ in $\mathbb{Z}_n$. Since $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is cyclic, all its subgroups are cyclic. Denote $([m])$ the subgroup generated by $[m]$. Recall that $([m])=([gcd(m,n)])$ where $gcd(m,n)$ is the greatest common divisor of $m$ and $n$. From these facts, you can determine all subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_n$.

Comment: Hint : for every divisor $d$ of $n$, there is exactly one subgroup of order $d$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ and this gives all the subgroups. Edit : Sorry, Frank Lu, we posted at the same moment.

Comment: Please ask *one* question at a time.

Comment: Thanks you all!

Comment: Those who have marked the Question as **Duplicate** let me tell you that I have joined this website yesterday and don't know whether the question exits. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

Denote by $d(n)$ the number of positive divisors of $n$. Then $\mathbb{Z}_n$ has $d(n)$ subgroups, because a cyclic group of order $n$ has a unique subgroup for each divisor $d\mid n$, see here:

[Subgroups of a cyclic group and their order.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/410389/subgroups-of-a-cyclic-group-and-their-order)

Since $d(200)=12$, we are done.

Comment: You are welcome!