# How to find the number of elements with a particular order in a cyclic group?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

How can I find the number of elements of order $d$ (where $d$ divide $n$) in a cyclic group $G$ generated by $g$ of order $n$?
I try to find all the elements $g^k\in G$ such that $o(g^k)=\frac{n}{gcd\{k,n\}}=d$ but in this way I have to test it for every $g\in G$. So my question is: is there a faster way to count it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the key facts:

- An element of order $d$ generates a cyclic subgroup of order $d$.
- Every subgroup of a finite cyclic group of order $n$ is cyclic of order a divisor of $n$.
- A cyclic group of order $n$ has exactly one subgroup of order $d$ for each divisor $d$ of $n$.
- A cyclic group of order $d$ has $\phi(d)$ generators.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: @MayoDancer, in a cyclic group of order $m$, there are exactly $\phi(m)$ generators.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/410464/589