# Partition integer range (1 to n) as multiples of divisors of n

Tags: prime-factorization

*Positive integers everywhere.*

I need to partition a set `{1, 2, 3, ..., n}` into disjoint subsets, one for each (not necessarily prime) divisor of n, such that

1. any divisor d divides every element in its allocated subset
2. no other divisor (> d) of n divides any element in that subset.

**I only need the sizes of the subsets, not the subsets themselves.**

It is kind of confusing to comprehend. Can you help me out?

Note -
A friend showed me this problem from their Mathematics paper. I'm not sure where it came from. So if you can find a source, can you put it here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* Let $X_d = \{ x \in \{1,2,\dots,n\} : ord_n(x)=n/d \}$.

Here, $ord_n(x)$ is the additive order of $x$ mod $n$.

Comment: I thought point #2 made this useless.

Comment: @nomad, no, because $d \in X_d$. Actually, $d = \min X_d$.

Comment: So you're saying there's a direct function from the additive order to the size of the partition?

Comment: Yes. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2782281/589