# Cyclic group of order n

Tags: group-theory

*Let **G** be a cyclic group of order **n**, and let **r** be an integer dividing **n**. Prove that **G** contains exactly one subgroup of order **r***

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Probable duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/410389/subgroups-of-a-cyclic-group-and-their-order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic (You should be able to see that, but if you have problems with that, let me know). Then take any subgroup $H$ of order $r$ diving $n$ and take $g$ a generator of the whole group. Then set

$$
s=min\{k\in\mathbb Z| g^k\in H\}
$$

Then you can prove $H=\left<g^s\right>$ (by contradiction for instance). And as $H$ has order $r$ we bust have that the order of $g^s$ is $r$ and you can conclude $s=n/r$. I leave you to fill the details, but that should do it.